# Dumpfile on RDS - Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-migration, amazon-rds, rds

I have requirement to move a dumpfile to Oracle RDS instance, I have referred http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html and I understand it can be achieved using dbms file transfer but I have couple of questions:

1) Lets say I have a dumpfile locally, can't I directly upload it? Need i always have to setup a database and then use dbms_file_transfer to move it? Often data center will not have access to Internet so always we would need a jum database?

2) Let's say our dump file is f 600 GB (multiple files of 25GB) how easy, reliable it will be to move these files on RDS. I understand it very much depends on network speed and distance still is dbms file transfer is reliable method for transferring 600+ GB of data?

Thanks in advance

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I did import the database for this manual.
It is necessary to take several steps.

```
1) Create a free instance of EC2 or a paid instance with a large disk.
2) Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version.
3) Copy several files to the DUMP directory (the free instance of EC2 has a limit of 30 GB) 
via the sftp protocol. (The speed depends on your Internet provider, downloading the oracle installation package from oracle.com was at a speed of 30 MB per second)
4) Transfer files to the RDS instance.
5) Delete files in the DUMP directory
6) repeat the steps 3,4,5 to transfer 600 GB.
```